# SwiftUI how to force a divider for navigation bar in NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui

My app has simple navigation logic using navigation view. I use the `inline` style navigation bar:

```
mainView
  .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

I notice that the navigation bar's divider is missing for the root view. And it appears when I scroll up the content a bit.

This first screenshot shows the initial state (without nav bar divider):

[image]

This second screenshot shows the state when I scroll up the content a bit, and it shows nav bar divider:

[image]

Is it possible to always show the divider without scrolling?

Comment: not in pure SwiftUI. You have to go into UIKit to control that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can work around by adding a manual Divider and ScrollView under VStack so that the divider will appear beneath the navigation bar

```swift
//
//  testUI.swift
//  DDStore (iOS)
//
//  Created by belal medhat on 19/02/2022.
//

import SwiftUI

struct navTitleBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // main navigationView
            VStack() {
                // vstack to add the divider and under it the scrollview
                Divider()
                ScrollView() {
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline).navigationTitle("Title")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct testUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        navTitleBar()
    }
}
```

[image]